# Database Idle Connections Not Activating

Tags: oracle12c, hikaricp

While performing Stress test of my application, I observed that my application was not consuming more than 1 connection from connection pool. Though there were idle connections in the pool, but my app used only 1 connection. As I increased stress on my application, consumption of just 1 connection started resulting in JDBC Connection unavailable and because of that I could not complete stress test of my application.

I am using Hikari CP v3.4.5 with Oracle 12c Database with below config:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: url
    username: username
    password: password
    driver-class: driver class name
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      javax:
        persistence:
          sharedCache:
            mode: ENABLE_SELECTIVE
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

I am expecting my app to dynamically start consumption of more idle connections from pool when 1 connection is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

DBAs were not able to get the accurate status of connections as they were checking using a query. But by enabling TRACE level logs for Hikari, we were able to determine that the connection pooling is working as expected.